# How do I view my favorited posts in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2

In *Splatoon 1*, favorited in-game drawings seen in Inkopolis Plaza were linked to Miiverse, meaning I could view any favorited post by checking my Miiverse profile.

*Splatoon 2* also has in-game drawings which can be marked as "fresh". However, now that Miiverse integration is gone, I can't find any record of my favorite posts.

**How can I view artwork I've marked as "fresh" in *Splatoon 2*?**

Followup question: if there is no way to search favorited art, what happens when a post is marked as fresh? Does marking a post do anything?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. You may be able to find and save/bookmark some art by searching Twitter with the "Splatoon2" and "NintendoSwitch" hashtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to view the posts you've marked "fresh".

From the looks of it, the "fresh" marker is essentially used to make post more likely to appear in other people's plazas.

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/6p62r4/does_saying_fresh_at_a_drawing_do_anything/):

> You can’t see the amount, but yes. The more “Fresh!” a drawing gets, the more likely it is to show up in people’s games

[Here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/6p6ba0/how_do_you_view_your_own_drawings/) another thread that supports this as well:

> It appears in random people’s plazas. The more people “Fresh!” your drawings, the more likely it is to appear in other people’s plazas